# Background with setup link for seasonal campaigns (opencart)

Tags: php, background, opencart

I need to implement for my client the option for him to add a clickable background image on body + setup link.

Also he wants to choose from backgrounds. For e.g if is black friday he wants to choose black friday background theme and then to setup the link for his campaign.

Is there a module for this ? And if is not how would you do it ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a module, but one way to do it is to set up a banner in the Admin called "Clickable Background" or something. (Whatever name you choose, though, it can never change, so be sure to let your client know this) But don't add it to any positions / pages.

In your `header.php` controller, then find this banner by name (hence why it can never change) and take the image and link from it.

You can set it up in `header.tpl` to be the background image, make it clickable (maybe using Javascript / JQuery if all else fails).

Then whenever he wants to change the background, he can go into Banners and change the banner called "Clickable Background"